# How does SameSite=strict function when doing a POST-Redirect-GET From an outside site

Tags: session, cookies, sakai

We want to set SameSite=strict for our Session Cookie for our application.   But we have certain very special situations (IMS Deep Linking) where we want to allow an external site to POST to a very particular URL and use/maintain the logged-in status of a user.  I have added a token parameter to re-establish the session without a Cookie so I can process the POST without needing the SESSION cookie - this may not be elegant but it works fine.

But then this POST handling code finishes its work and does a re-direct back to itself which causes the browser to issue a GET request.  In the resulting GET request, the browser does not include the SESSION cookie.

This seems weird since the redirect is coming from the *my server* (i.e. not the external server).

So my question is whether the spec for SameSite expects a POST-ReDirect-GET sequence as a single operation that gets no cookies even though my system accepted the POST and the redirect came from my system?

I have worked around this by adding a token to the the GET url to do a second temporary bypass of the need for a Cookie and then from that point forward everything works well - the user is still logged in from that point forward.  The cookie was always there - it was just not send on the POST or the redirected GET.

I am using Chrome in all this.   Since my FireFox ignores SameSite for my current version - the cookies just come in like before SameSite (for a little while).

I think our implementation will use SameSite=strict and a whitelist of URLs that are allowed to do the bypass trick and those URLs will need to have a special token to do the bypass and those URLs protect themselves in other ways than just login cookie.

But I would like to make sure that I am basing my design on a solid understanding of SameSite=strict and POST-Redirect.

P.S. There is no point in telling me to rewrite the other side of the interaction so as to not require a ForeignSite POST in a browser to work.  It is a spec that I don't control wth lots of implementations out there in the wild that I need to interoperate with.